# Generate a MAC ID for authorization prior to execution of REST API JMETER Test

Tags: rest, authentication, jmeter, apigee

Our APIs generate a MAC ID for authorization prior to execution.  We can do it successfully in soapUI and need to find out how to do it in JMETER.  Does anyone have any experience running APIGEE REST APIs with MAC IDs that could help?

Comment: MAC ID as in the unique identifier associated with your network card?

Comment: how do you do it with soap ui ?

Comment: MAC Ids as in Message Authentication Code